# Can we Integrate Salesforce Sales Cloud data with Social Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, social-studio

I have an account set up with Marketing Cloud Connect.
Can I sync Sales cloud and Social studio?
- Suppose If I want to track/post on the Facebook account of my Contact/Leads [along with their consent]!

Answer (score 2):

Social Studio cannot post to private accounts of your leads, you can only manage posts on e.g. your company page.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas ...... Can you also confirm that if we can INTEGRATE SalesCloud and SocialStudio? Similarly how we integrate Contacts and Leads from SalesCloud to Contacts in Marketing cloud!

Comment: No, as Social Studio does not hold any customer data as such. It can integrate to Service Cloud, so you can create cases directly from social posts of your followers.